# Google Chrome and VLC do not open in Kali 2.0

Tags: kali-linux, chrome, vlc

I installed Google Chrome in Kali 2.0 but it does not open with no error messages. Also VLC does not open. Error message of VLC while opening through terminal is

> VLC is not supposed to be run as root. Sorry.
>   If you need to use real-time priorities and/or privileged TCP ports
>   you can use vlc-wrapper (make sure it is Set-UID root and
>   cannot be run by non-trusted users first).

Is there any way to solve these issues.

Comment: Why are you running VLC as root? Are you logged in as root while trying this? What happens if you don't run VLC as root?

Comment: `VLC is not supposed to be run as root` means it is not recommended to run `vlc` as a `root` for security and other reasons. What is your reason to run `vlc` as `root` anyway? It seems very BAD idea, to me.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is not advisable to run the applications as `root`, but there is a way to do that.

#### Steps:

1. `cd /usr/lib/chromium-browser`
2. `hexedit chromium-browser`
3. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> - This switches you to ascii
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> - Search for **geteuid**
5. Modify it to **getppid**
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> - To exit saving changes

Follow the same steps for `vlc` as well on `/usr/bin/vlc`

**Note**: To undo any changes you might do by mistake after ***Step 5*** use <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

Comment: It worked out for VLC but not for Google Chrome. There is no geteuid in chrome. And I also want to know what was this error I got and how was it solved by changing some phrase to other

Comment: `which chromium` ? or `which google-chrome` ? what's the output ?

Comment: its google-chrome not chromium

Comment: What's the output of `which google-chrome` ? `vi /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome` & append `--user-data-dir` to the last line.

Comment: actually first thing i did was that.... it did not help appending `--user-data-dir`

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by typing the following commands
cp /usr/bin/vlc /usr/bin/vlc-backup

needle=$(objdump -d /usr/bin/vlc | grep euid | tail -1 | awk '{print "\x"$2"\x"$3"\x"$4"\x"$5"\x"$6;}')

sed -ir "s/$needle/\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00/" /usr/bin/vlc